# If $F,G$ are cumulative distributions functions, then is $F+G-FG$ also one?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, proof-verification, probability-distributions

As the title suggests, I am interested answering the question "If $F,G$ are cumulative distributions functions, then is $F+G-FG$ also one?"

Let $H=F+G-FG$. What I have to show is that $H$ is non-decreasing, right-continuous, and that $\lim_{x\to\infty}H(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}H(x)=0$.

I'm confident that I have proved all the required properties except right-continuity.

By definition, I need to show that $\lim_{y\to x\;:\;y>x}H(y)=H(x)$.

So far, I have

\begin{align}
\lim_{y\to x\;:\;y>x}H(y)&=\lim_{y\to x\;:\;y>x}\big[F(x)+G(x)-F(x)G(x)\big]\\
&=\lim_{y\to x\;:\;y>x}F(y)+\lim_{y\to x\;:\;y>x}G(y)-\lim_{y\to x\;:\;y>x}F(y)G(y)\\
&=F(x)+G(x)-F(x)G(x)\\
&=H(x)
\end{align}
The result should now follow as $F,G$, and $FG$ are distribution functions and also the sum of distribution functions is a distribution function.

Is that enough to answer the question? I'd appreciate any hints.

Comment: Alternatively, you can define a random variable $Z$ with that distribution $$P[Z\leq x] = P[X\leq x] + P[Y\leq x] - P[X\leq x]P[Y\leq x] \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: I think you should explain your step when you claim: $...=F(x) + G(x) - F(x)G(x)$.  Your existing proof seems to simply claim the answer with no justification.

Comment: Hint: $F+G-FG=1-(1-F)(1-G)$

Comment: @Michael by assumption both $F$ and $G$ are distribution functions, so we already know that $\lim_{y\to x\;:\; y>x}F(y)=F(x)$ and $\lim_{y\to x\;:\; y>x}G(y)=G(x)$ (similarly for the product of distribution functions).

Comment: So you should state that in your proof.  Even the way you stated it just now, it is not clear if you know whether or not you are using "continuity" or "right-continuity."

Comment: Your proof is good, as long as you take it as a given that $\lim (f+g)=\lim f + \lim g$ and $\lim fg=(\lim f)(\lim g)$, which you use in the second and third equalities. The interesting part of this problem is showing that $F+G-FG$ is increasing.

Comment: @MikeEarnest why would that be interesting? the sum of increasing functions is increasing, right?

Comment: @johnny09 Yes, the _sum_ of increasing functions is increasing, but the _difference_ of increasing functions is not always increasing. The minus sign in $F+G\color{red}-FG$ is what causes problems.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I have been trying the last two days to understand how your hint can help me but failed. Could you please elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: Knowing that $F+G-FG=1-(1-F)(1-G)$ makes it clear that $F+G-FG$ is right-continuous and non-decreasing.